# How can i also share my custom OneNote templates in a shared notebook?

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-onenote, templates, sharing

I have created a OneNote notebook with custom templates that I'm sharing with external partners. When one of these partners creates a new page in a notebook-section, the custom template is not applied. The custom templates should always be applied to new pages. Any idea on how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's not easy to share templates across users. They need to consciously and actively add the current page as a template.

- Open the shared notebooks, go to each page they want to use as a
  template.
- Go to Insert > Page Templates > Save the current page as a template
  （In the lower right corner）

[image]

Even within the organization, there is no good way to [centrally manage templates](https://onenote.uservoice.com/forums/327186-onenote-for-windows-windows-phone/suggestions/17996623-centrally-manage-templates) to let everyone uses the same OneNote templates. Some people have the same requirements, they voted this thread and expect Microsoft to develop related new features.